# Need to Destroy() Hidden Root Window?

Tags: python, memory-management, tkinter, garbage-collection, messagebox

If I use `tkinter` for the `messagebox` functionality only and hide the root window, do I have to *explicitly* destroy the root window before the script exits?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

answer = tk.messagebox.askyesno('Confirm', 'Save file?')
# do work here ...

root.destroy() # <-- do I need this?
```

Comment: I would because if you don't and you run from the console, you may get weird TclError messages printed when auto-gc destroys things in the wrong order.  Also, add 'parent=root' to the messagebox call, as I believe a second Tk() call may happen internally without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Well, that's not literally true. You can call `sys.exit()` to exit immediately, for example. Tkinter's mainloop -- an infinite loop which processes events -- is designed to run until the root window is destroyed.

Comment: I am not calling `mainloop()` explicitly in this script. Does the mainloop still run? I guess my question is, when the script ends, will it destroy the hidden root window same as the explicit `root.destroy()`? Most examples I have seen showing the use of a hidden root window do not bother with `root.destroy()`.

Comment: @coding4fun: I don't know, I've never coded it that way. In general, you must run `mainloop`. Depending on the platform, maybe it uses something different when you show a standard dialog.